# Problems with code listing unique items in a list and copying them into new worksheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run the following code on a spreadsheet.  The column of names is the 4th column.  I'm attempting to run through that list of names, pushing each new unique name to an array (listOfNames), and then add a new worksheet (NamesList), and finally add the array to cell A1 of the new worksheet.  When I run the code below, all I get is a blank popup with an OK and Cancel button.  When I view the log, it is blank as well.  I'm quite new at this, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious... just not sure what it is.  Am I misunderstanding something specific to GAS rather than JS?

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var listOfNames = new Array ();

function copyNames() {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i=0; i<=sheet.getLastRow(); i++){
    var tempName = sheet.getDataRange(i,4).getValue();
    for (i=0; i<=listOfNames.length; i++){
      if (tempName != listOfNames[i]){
        listOfNames.push(tempName);
        logger.log(listOfNames);
      }
    }
  }
sheet.insertSheet(ListOfEDs);
sheet.getRange('a1').setValue(listOfEDs);
}
```

Edit:  I'm starting to see that this will push values multiple times to the list... so maybe it's just back to the drawing board all together.  I have found other code that would create a list of unique elements, but wasn't really sure how that code worked.  I thought I'd try to figure it out myself so I'd at least understand it.

EDIT 2:  Ok... I tried some new code, but I'm still getting a blank message box, and nothing on the log.  I wasn't sure if having i be the iterator for a for loop within a for loop was a bad thing, so I switched it to j.  Also, I know there's the [remove duplicates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) example, and have been looking at that, but am unsure why one needs to use join.

```
function copyNames() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var listOfNames = new Array ();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i=2; i<=data.length; i++){ //starting at 2 because first row is a header
    var tempName = data[i][4];
    for (j=0; j<=listOfNames.length+1; j++){
        if (tempName != listOfNames[j]){
          listOfNames.push(tempName);
          logger.log(listOfNames);
        }
      }
    }
sheet.insertSheet("ListOfNames");
sheet.getRange('a1').setValue(listOfNames);
}
```

Comment: So do you want us to give you a solution or point out your mistakes and give advice?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you went help instead of a ready solution, so here you go.

**First:**

Try to avoid using global variables. Keep all your variables inside of your functions. Otherwise you will have issues when you add more functions to your spreadsheet. Your Code should start like this:

```
function copyNames() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var listOfNames = new Array ();
```

**Second:**

Try to decrease the amount of service calls to spreadsheet. it takes several seconds for your script to go to your sheet and take the values. Instead of doing it each time, take these values once and push them in to a variable.

In your case, you already did that, however did not use that variable and kept using service calls. Check this line:

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Now all of the data on that sheet is in a variable called **data**.

```
sheet.getDataRange(i,4).getValue();
```

is the same as

```
data[i][4];
```

The only difference is that in the first case it will take approximately 2 seconds to get that value, while in the second case only a few milliseconds.

Same goes for

```
sheet.getLastRow();
```

Either call it once and push it into a variable and use that, or in your case just use

```
data.length;
```

**Third:**

*listOfNames* is an empty array, so it's length is 0.
This line

```
for (i=0; i<=listOfNames.length; i++)
```

will not even run, as both **i** and **listOfNames.length** is 0.
That is why you logger does not give any output. Your script never get's to that line.

**Fourth:**

You do not have a variable called **ListOfEDs**, therefore your last two rows of code just give an error. Your script does not know what is **ListOfEDs** as it doesn't exist.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly the type of feedback I feel like I'm missing when I'm trying to learn to code from a book.  I honestly never understood how the whole calling the spreadsheet thing worked, but that was a great, clear explanation.  I'm going to take another crack at this.

Comment: Keep improving your code, and we will help you as you go on